# Disable Intellisense in Blend 3

Tags: intellisense, expression-blend, expression-blend-3

We are currently building a WPF solution in Blend 3 and Intellisense is extremely slow.

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 beta 2 do not have any problems, Blend 2 did not have any issues either.

How would it be possible to disable Intellisense in the XAML editor.

Many Thanks,

KShaban

Comment: Yes, please God someone tell me how to disable the retarded reflection loving intellisense in Blend...  My assemblies don't reflect and it causes serious hangs...

Answer (score 1):

What was actually causing the problem for me was that my UI project had a lot of external assemblies referenced.  Specifically, it was referencing some DevExpress Winforms stuff for reporting needs.

Once I refactored the UI project to not depend on those dependencies Blend started working great.

As a note, I attached a debugger to Blend while it was hanging and it seems that Blend keeps re-reflecting over those same assemblies.  Also, the assemblies in question were not in the GAC.

The funny thing is VS2008 or VS2010 do not choke at all as far as intellisense on the same project.

Hope it helps.